# Ubuntu 12.04, ruby installation

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, ruby, rvm

I'm new to Ubuntu and Ruby and I have a problem, which seems to be strange. I needed to install Ubuntu because of problems with Ruby on Windows.

I've installed Ruby, v. 1.9.3 (the same as I had on Windows). When I launched `bundle install`, I got this error message:

```
Installing nokogiri (1.6.0) /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:388:in ensure_required_ruby_version_met': nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2. (Gem::InstallError)
```

- But I **have** `version >= 1.9.2`.

  `Ruby -v` returns me  `ruby 1.8.7`. Strange, I installed 1.9.3.
- When I tried `rvm install 1.9.3`, the message was `Already installed ruby-1.9.3.-p547`.

  `Which ruby` returns me `/usr/bin/ruby` - because there is only one Ruby version.

I used this tutorial http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/, just write `1.9.3` instead of `2.1.0`.

Projects are made in Ruby 1.9.3, there should be any problems when using newer one, it's the real reason why I tried to install this elder ruby version.

Any idea what does this version mess mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matters how did you installed the software manually or by apt-get command 
as you are with 12.04 you will not get the versions that are made after the release of 12.04 directly , I mean if you do a

sudo apt-get install

definetly you will get the version on the universe of your version(older at the time of release of 12.04).

If you need new version download the new pacakge from the website and install it manually...

https://leonard.io/blog/2012/05/installing-ruby-1-9-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pengolin/

or you can download a package from here and unpack a tar ball and then follow the instructions

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/installation/#building-from-source